# Unable to login in phpPgAdmin

Tags: linux, centos, psql, postgresql

I am trying to login to phpPgAdmin from a remote client. I've created the user root, but when I login phpPgAdmin returns an error message saying "Unable to login"

When I check the log it says: "provided user name (root) and authenticated user name (apache) do not match".

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the configuration file of phpPgAdmin please ?
How did you configure PostgreSQL in pg_hba.conf ?

Answer (score -1):

```
# sudo su - postgres
# psql -d template1
template1=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new password';
# service postgresql restart
```

https://superuser.com/questions/414482/how-to-change-root-password-for-postgresql-phppgadmin

Comment: I'm not trying to change my root password though. I have already set my password.